# Data get discarded while I am using kafkastream aggregate method

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

I recently encountered a thorny problem, while I am using kafkastream's TimeWindowedKStream aggregation method. The phenomenon was that I stopped my program for 5 minutes and then restarted it. I found a small part of my data was lost and got the following prompt, "Skipping record for expired window". All data are normal data that want to be saved, there is no large delay.  What can I do to prevent data from being discarded ?  It seems that kafkastream got a later time when it got observedstreamtime

Comment: What type of windowing are you using? https://kafka.apache.org/10/documentation/streams/developer-guide/dsl-api.html#windowing Depending on the type if the grace period has expired the records will not be considered. Also the time considered to process the event depend on some configuration which you can also control with an TimestampExtractor -> https://kafka.apache.org/31/documentation/streams/core-concepts#streams_time

Comment: Thanks for groo's advice. I am using 'Tumbling time window' and I already have an TimestampExtrator.  The time of the data might be a little earlier than the current time but the grace period would not expired I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message means that a window was already closed -- thus you would need to increase GRACE as pointed out by @groo. -- Data expiration is based on event-time so stopping your program and resuming is later should not change much.

However, if there is a repartition topic before the aggregation, if you stop your program for some time, there might be more out-of-order data inside the repartition topic, because the input topic is read much faster than in the "live run" -- this increased unorder during catchup could be the issue.

Comment: Thanks @Matthias J. Sax, I did have a repartition topic before the aggregation. So what you described may be the reason for my data loss. I want to further study this issue. Are there any relevant articles or blog recommendations. Is there any way to solve this problem? Thank you very much for solving the problem that has bothered me for a long time @@Matthias J. Sax

Comment: Atm, you can only increase the grace period. In the end, it's a "runtime problem" and it must be solved by Kafka Streams itself.